# Sql cursor and stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a stored procedure. There is 3 biggest record date in order table. I want to read the IDs one by one and send a stored procedure, but it gives an error.

```
BEGIN TRAN

exec trn_siparis_insert 'Database',348

DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier 

DECLARE SIPARIS CURSOR FOR

    Select id from TABLE.dbo.siparis  where kayit_tarihi = (SELECT MAX(kayit_tarihi) FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis );

    OPEN SIPARIS 

    FETCH NEXT FROM SIPARIS INTO @ID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
        BEGIN

            BEGIN TRAN

            exec trn_boyutlu_siparis_olustur @siparis_id=@ID, @TargetDb='Database'

            FETCH NEXT FROM SIPARIS INTO @ID

        END

    CLOSE SIPARIS 

    DEALLOCATE SIPARIS 

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: your commit tran seems badly placed anyway...

Comment: You have a begin tran which is never ended.

Comment: BEGIN TRAN should be moved to just before the WHILE

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN TRAN should be moved to just before the WHILE:

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier 

DECLARE SIPARIS CURSOR FOR

Select id from TABLE.dbo.siparis  where kayit_tarihi = (SELECT MAX(kayit_tarihi) FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis );

OPEN SIPARIS 

FETCH NEXT FROM SIPARIS INTO @ID

BEGIN TRAN

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    BEGIN

        exec trn_boyutlu_siparis_olustur @siparis_id=@ID, @TargetDb='Database'

        FETCH NEXT FROM SIPARIS INTO @ID

    END

COMMIT TRAN 

CLOSE SIPARIS 

DEALLOCATE SIPARIS
```